# iMessage syncing on two separate phones and saving imessages

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, messages

Feel free in your response to tell me as if I was a 2 years old as I come from Android. I know it ended up lengthy so thank you in advance!

So my teenage daughter has been deleting messages and lying about it (surprise, teenager).

What I am trying to do is have the iMessage synced to two different phones but not allow them to be deleted from one or deleted from the other.

- Phone 1: her current phone she uses to communicate
- Phone 2: a phone we plan/planned on her getting. Currently a wifi only device.

*What I would like is for the iMessages from phone 1 to also go to phone 2 but also **stay** on phone 2 even if she tries deleting them on phone 1.*

This way she can't hide her messages and such, which seems overbearing but she has mental health issues and she has deleted texts that are negative in nature to give a facade about being okay/better.

So far I have logged her iCloud into both devices, set messages up to sync to iCloud as well as set the iCloud login as the primary messaging "number" for iMessage specifically.

I have also put on text forwarding that (if my understanding is accurate) would allow us to text from phone 2 if necessary.

Will this have the desired effect? So far based on experimentation, when I deleted a message on iPhone 1 it stayed on iPhone 2 even after syncing with the cloud.